# Composer update error, RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Adding a dependency to a Laravel project and then running composer update shoots an error that it cannot find the appropriate path. Here is the error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing danielstjules/stringy (1.9.0)
  - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.10.0)    

  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(U:\home\nickmitchko\Site\vendor/danielstjules/stringy): failed to open dir: No error
```

[image: Error From PhpStorm]

Here you can see the directory is actually accessible:

[image: Directory is actually accessible]

Anyone know a work around, it looks as if the path delimiter is different throughout the path string here:

```
RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(...)
```

**Update 1:**

The error still occurs when the path has no spaces.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/var-dumper (v2.6.9)
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.6.11)



  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(U:\home\nickmitchko\Documents\CMW\MXDSite\vendor/symfony/var-dumper/Symfony/Component/VarDumper): failed to op  
  en dir: No error
```

Comment: Does this happen to all dependencies? Might be the path. Perhaps the space needs escaping. Can you try to setup your project in a path with no spaces?

Comment: I'll try that. Oddly enough, the same exact project works perfectly on linux

Comment: That wasn't it, still throws the same error.

Comment: Can you try `composer install --no-scripts` ?

Comment: That also throws the same error, in the meantime I've decided to go back to ubuntu.